# How do I make nothing selected in my jQuery UI slider by default?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, default

I'm using jQuery 2.1 and jQuery UI 1.11.1.  I want to setup a slider on my page, which I do using the below JS

```
$(function() {
    $(".slider")
    .slider({
        max: 12,
        change: function(event, ui) { 
            alert(ui.value); 
        }
    })
    .slider("pips", {
        rest: "label"
    });
});
```

The issue is, it looks like the option "0" is initially selected and I would like the tick graphic not to appear on the slider until someone clicks somewhere -- http://jsfiddle.net/u72596ta/4/ .  How do I set up my slider so taht no tick mark appears until someone clicks something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the handler after the slider created, then show it after value changed.

```
$(function() {
    $(".slider")
    .slider({
        max: 12,
        value:'',
        create: function(event, ui) {
              $(".ui-slider-handle").hide();
        },
        change: function(event, ui) { 
            $(".ui-slider-handle").show().focus();
            //alert(ui.value); 
        }
    })
    .slider("pips", {
        rest: "label"
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u72596ta/7/

Answer (score 0):

Simply just remove the classes

```
 $(function() {
        $(".slider")
        .slider({
            max: 12,
            change: function(event, ui) { 
                alert(ui.value); 
            }
        })
        .slider("pips", {
            rest: "label"
        });
      $('.ui-slider-pip-initial').removeClass('ui-slider-pip-selected');
        $('.ui-slider-pip-initial').removeClass('ui-slider-pip-initial');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the slider handle with:

```
.ui-slider-handle {
  display: none;
}
```

And if you add `$('.ui-slider-handle').show()` to your change method it will appear when it's clicked on.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/p56c3Le6/)**